# .attr not working in jquery varible

Tags: jquery

in my developer tools an error appears saying: 

script.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined at script.js:5

```
var $cell = $('td');
var psib = $cell.previousSibling;
var nsib = $cell.nextSibling;
$cell.addClass('o');
var $nsibclass = nsib.attr('class') //script.js:5
```

Comment: kindly implement you example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link

Comment: try `$(nsib).attr('class')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cell` is a jQuery object, which possibly contains a collection of elements.

So you should do something like `$cell.get(0).previousSibling;`, which will give you the "previous sibling" of the **first** `<td>` element in the DOM.

So, in order to get the class of the next sibling of `<td>`, you can do:

`var nsibclass = $($cell.get(0)).next().attr('class');`

For more info about `$.next()`, read here: https://api.jquery.com/next/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//class of next sibling
var $nextclass = $('td').next('td').attr('.class') //script.js:5
//class of prev sibling
var $precclass = $('td').prev('td').attr('.class') //script.js:5
```

Comment: Please see my comment. `nsib` is not defined and therefore your code will (also) throw an error.